# Laravel blade object requires json_decode

Tags: json, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel 5.2.

I've read docs and watched some laracasts and it looks like you're supposed to be able to do:

`{!! Form::model($samlMetadata) !!}`

and then do things like

`<h1>{{ $samlMetadata->name }}</h1>`

But I'm having to do this:

`{!! Form::model(json_decode($samlMetadata)) !!}`

What am I missing?

**Update - more code**

I added route model binding just to see if that made any difference (it didn't)

```
use Input;
use Login\Http\Requests;
use Login\SamlMetadata;
use Redirect;
use Request;

class EditSamlMetadataController extends Controller
...
/**
 * @param SamlMetadata $samlMetadata
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View
 */
public function show(SamlMetadata $samlMetadata)
{
    return view('samlMetadata.show', compact('samlMetadata'));
}
```

If I dd($samlMetadata) it certainly looks like a Laravel/Eloquent object.

Comment: How are you passing your `$object` in - i.e what does your controller function look like?

Comment: A result of a find() on my model class. I have the same issue on my foreach in my index route and the I'm passing the result of the all() method. It's as if I'm referencing a wrong class somewhere.

Comment: Can you post the actual code from your controller?

Comment: Updated my code posting.